ECK form in modal
I am opening an eck form in a modal but when I save the new entity it redirects me to the newly created entity rather than close the modal.
I can't work out how to make it save the new entity and close the modal.
I want to avoid a form alter if possible because I don't want to modify the form outside of the context of the modal where it's used in other locations.
